# Use SVN in opencms to keep versioning of site content

Tags: opencms

I am working with 10.5.4. I would like to use SVN to keep versioning of my site contents so as editors to be able to commit their changes. I have read a lot about mounting the VFS and that stuff, however with that way everyone coulld access and commit others changes
I would appreciate any further information about using versioning not only for module developments but also for site contents

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is probably not exactly what you are looking for, but you may have a look at the OpenCms Maven plugin.
The main focus of this plugin is, to ease the development process of OpenCms projects. But with a good setup and Maven configuration you might use it to put the contents of your production site under version control. If you are interested, you'll find more information on [the official website of the plugin](https://opencms-maven.comundus.com/).